# Which is the best scout weapon for range or damage?

Tags: battlefield-1

I think that the best weapon for a scout is the one with longer range or bigger damage. You can't have both of them, so:

Which is the scout weapon with the longest range? and

Which is the scout weapon that delivers more damage (to infrantry)?

Comment: 2 downgrades for my question, should I add that I'm new to the game? And that I'm not familiar with the weapons or its features?

Comment: the biggest difference in scout weapons is the bullet velocity and the damage ratio vs distance. So it will depend on your play style, will you be sniping at mid or longe range or will you be going semi CQC without a scope. The game is still mostly about skill and less about good weapons. This youtube user has a lot of videos about sniping and you'll see he is a great sniper and only uses the starting rifle https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bwIXQrj1vu4

Comment: It's unfortunate (and impolite) when people down-vote without explanation, since it doesn't help you learn. These downvotes are probably because questions of the form "What is the best [X]" are unwelcome, since they appear to be subjective ("What's the best RTS game?") However, the question you're asking is actually objective. I recommend rewording the title to something more like, "Which scout rifles have the longest range and highest damage?" -- if that captures what you're trying to ask. That will make the objective nature of your question more obvious.

Comment: @FeralChimp Downvotes are meant to be anonymous, there's nothing unfortunate or impolite about not leaving a comment. And of course, downvotes are not close votes, so thinking someone used one instead of the other is just ignoring the issue.

Comment: @FeralChimp Downvotes are not personal, therefore cannot be impolite.  They're not for the poster; they're for future readers.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer Fair enough. People are of course free and welcome to downvote without commenting. And "polite" was a poor choice of words. But I do feel it's unfortunate, since the community works better if we take a moment to explain.

Comment: Would it be better to say it is far less helpful when users downvote without giving any comment feedback on why they're downvoting?

Comment: @Guy Yes, if you go to meta, there are tons of discussion topics talking about leaving feedback along with downvoting

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most all of the scout weapons, excluding trench variants, are capable of lethal damage when they are in their lethal ranges. Lethal range is easiest to tell in the game by scrolling through the weapons. By lethal I mean chest up, all Scout rifles will be lethal with headshot at most any range.

But you can also see a chart [Here](http://symthic.com/bf1-ttk-btk-charts?scout=1&btk=1)

A quick rundown in case link is dead, or people don't want to check. Numbers +/- a few.

- Gewehr 98 = 80-120 meters
- Lebel Model 1886 = 50-80 meters
- SMLE MKIII = 40-80 meters
- Martini-Henry = 30-80 meters
- Mosin-Nagant M91 = 60-90 meters
- M1903 = 100-150 meters
- Gewehr M.95 = never lethal :(
- Vetterli-Vitali M1870 = 20-50 meters
- Russian 1895 = 60-100 meters

Going by this. The M1903 has the farthest lethal range. But the hardest hitting rifle is the Martini-Henry at 112 dmg, while all others top at 100. The Martini's window is very small, though, and has really heavy fall-off while other scouts remain at 80

If you find yourself in long range engagements often **M1903** is your answer, otherwise **Mosin-Nagant or Russian 1895** are more reliable mid-range.

Personally, I prefer the power (although it's hard to find its sweet spot) of the Martini-Henry. but for all purpose scouting fun I always fall back to Russian 1895 Infantry.